# HTML5 number input with polyfill

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm using the HTML5 number input, with a polyfill (https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill) to handle older browsers.

The page / input is working good. I get to input values, use the spinner buttons, all great. But the value is formatted like "0.00", default en-US culture. The site I'm building runs on the Dutch culture settings, which uses "0,00" for number formatting.

Now upon postback, MVC reads "4.6" as "46", which obviously isn't what I want. So now I'm looking for a good way of dealing with this. I know I could adapt the javascript or use a custom binder on the MVC side to fix the fault. But in that case I would be assuming that it's always one or the other format. Most ideally, I'd like to follow the users' setting (which is what MVC does on the serverside). So when an English users uses the site, he/she can enter "4.6" and Dutch users can enter "4,6".

But that's a "nice to have", if it's too complicated I'll go with Dutch style inputting for now.

Comment: I understand what are you talking about *(We also have to provide location based formats)*, BUT I cannot find any question. Are you asking how to accept client culture settings?

Comment: The polyfill library itself likely doesn't support locales. Have you considered filing a bug in Github?

Comment: @RadimKöhler I don't necessarily care about the clients settings. I just want the serverside and clientside to play nicely together in the same culture settings, wether it's the clients culture or a predefined one.

Comment: @Jasper, HTML5 introduced these new input types (number, date) and strongly specified their content. In a nutshell the format is 'invariant'. Now to job is on the Client side (mobile browsers, latest desktop browsers) - what workaround they will provide. E.g. DatePicker, slider etc. Other words, client side is opened and the more smart browsers will provide more comfort to the user. AND we can be sure, that to server will recieve always the 'standardized' number, date format. BTW, that's why I decided to keep type="text" and localize it on client with JS and on server with client culture

Comment: I solved it client side by a change event which reads the value as a number, and uses Globalize.format to write it to a hidden field. Still feels like a workaround though.